# C++ - how to convert colour values to RGB

Tags: c++, colors, rgb

I have the following colour values - 0xFFFF40, 0xFFFF20, 0xff5099.

I want to convert these C++ codes into RGB values, how would I need to go about doing this?

Thanks

Edit:
I would basically want to store these values in 3 different unsigned shorts:

```
unsigned short red;
unsigned short green;
unsigned short blue;
```

Comment: The color value `0xff5099` stands for a red value of `ff`, a green value of `50` and a blue value of `99`, what else do you need?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you want them stored when you're done converting and how you have them stored as-is?

Comment: hmm... I didn't know about that. Can I can ask does the '0x' means anything then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get each of the channels by masking them out individually:

```
// Original color
std::size_t color = 0xFFFF40;
std::size_t red   = (color & 0xff0000) >> 16;
std::size_t green = (color & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
std::size_t blue  = (color & 0x0000ff);
```

Comment: You'll probably want to shift them too.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Shifting is bits (16/8) not nibbles (4/2). ;)

Comment: Oh man. Today is just not my day :-/

Comment: Double facepalm -- http://ozhouse.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/double_facepalm.jpg

Comment: Let's call it a +1 and be done with it, we all have our downs. ;)